# Add site-packages path using Python CGI script

Tags: python, python-2.7, cgi, peewee

I'm want to use `peewee` library installed in `/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` directory in Python CGI script.

When I'm running the script from console everything works good, but when I'm running the script form CGI Python can't find the `peewee`. It happens because CGI scripts runs as a different user and has different environment: `sys.path` doesn't contain `/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` in this case.

I've tried to add `/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` manually to the `sys.path` before `import peewee` but it doesn't work. What should I do to make Python find this package?

Comment: it is your private folder so other users have no access. You can change folders privilage for reading (and probably for executing) for `/home/user/`, `/home/user/.local/`, etc.. Or install peewee in other user folder.

Comment: I've already set permission for the `/home/user/.local/` directory and all subdirectories, but nothing changed. I can't change peewee install directory and `home/user` directory privilege for security reasons.

Comment: if you can't change privilages for `home/user` then program may not have access to this module. I don't see solution.